# add css class to spring mvc tag

Tags: css, spring-mvc

i need add a css class yo a spring mvc tag, specifically to a input tag.

Now i have this

```
<field:input cssClass="form-control" disableFormBinding="true" field="roomNumber" id="f_es_iw_mahra_Room_roomNumber" required="true" z="
```

But spring console say this:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /WEB-INF/views/rooms/findRoomsByHotelAndRoomNumber.jspx(6,211) Attribute cssClass invalid for tag select according to TLD

How can i add a css class to spring tag?

Thanks.